# Random numbers in flex

Tags: win-prolog, lpa-flex

so im just getting to grips with flex and fuzzy logic. I wanted to create a simple chat system where based on what your choice of dialogue is the NPC would change what they say, but i want to make it a bit more unique and it currently gets the same output all the time.

```
rule mood_dialogue2
    if the_mood is hello
    then the_mood becomes 30 .

rule mood_dialogue3
    if the_mood is  'you`re an ogre?!'
    then the_mood becomes 50 .
```

As you can see the same numbers are input so i wanted to randomise this part within a range for example dialogue2 between 30 and 49 and dialogue3 between 50 and 100. i attempted this within something i saw in some documentation

```
then the_mood becomes irand(25) + 1 .
```

but i know that doesnt work as it actually stores`"irand(25) + 1" in the_mood

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this a question about the Adobe/Apache Flex UI Framework?  Or do you have it mistagged?

Comment: Its LPA WIN-PROLOG? my lecturer has it down as flex so im not entirely sure. Sorry if there is confusion :/

Comment: Unfortunately, "flex" can mean a lot of things: "Apache Flex", the lexer "flex", or the "Flex" expert system toolkit. It looks like the correct tag for your question is "lpa-flex".

Comment: Thanks, understand a bit more than i did already then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `rand` NOT `irand`

```
| ?- X is irand(25) + 1 .

! ----------------------------------------
! Error 50 : Function Not Defined
! Goal     : _36394 is irand(25) + 1

Aborted
| ?- X is rand(25) + 1 .
X = 13.1864792832639
```

Comment: Im afraid it did not work. i got this error after it ran, and let me select my options etc. it closed with this error.
`Rule : determine_dialogue_crisp_value has misfired ! 

Context stack:

! ----------------------------------------
! Error 1998 : Unknown Error
! Goal     : flex_runtime_error
`